# | operator operation?

Tags: c#

(pipe) operator in linq?i want to know operation of operator(|).i want to check multiple columns in different table.In my scenario only single table contain value for that perticular column.

my code:

&& swr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | spr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | scr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | smr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date

In this scenario only one table will contain date value others will contain dault values in their respected columns.

The above condition is not working,it takes default value.

what condition can i use to get correct value?